# Disable permanently wifi power management

Tags: wifi, wireless, power-management, wireless-adapter

After adding `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` to `/etc/rc.local`, I checked whether it has been applied with `iw wlan0 get power_save`. I notice that indeed it has been applied cause I get `Power save: off`. However, after a while when checking again, I get again `Power save: on`. Is there any way to make it permanent and by default deactivated? My board is:

```
description: ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
product: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Rev 1.0
network: logical_name=wlan0 broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=9.88.4 firmware=01-3b307371
```

Comment: You need to add the command to /etc/rc.local (or other auto-start), so that it runs at every reboot.

Comment: @Dougie Pretty sure that's what "After adding sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off to /etc/rc.local" meant...

Comment: @Gouz You should edit the question to clarify what "after a while" refers to.  Does it mean a few hours after boot?  Or does it mean a few days after a fresh reboot?  Point being if it is immediately after boot, it could be because of a race condition there such that sometimes this works and sometimes it does not.